# Spring CORS error on nginx reverse proxy with https

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, spring-security, cors

I configured nginx reverse proxy which terminates the ssl connection and then uses proxy_pass to forward the http connection to spring server.

On POST requests, I get CORS error. (Tested with Chrome)

The spring boot application has cors enabled. Here is the security config:

```java
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        HttpSecurity httpSecurity = http
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage(Urls.PUBLIC_LOGIN_PAGE)
                        .permitAll())

                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                )

        // Apply cors configuration
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(jpaCorsConfigurationSource);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

Here is the nginx config.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            include proxy_params;
        }
}
```

I tried sending a request to the nginx server, the GET requests work, but the POST requests fail with CORS error.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

Add `ForwardedHeaderFilter` to the filter chain.

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        HttpSecurity httpSecurity = http
                .addFilterBefore(new ForwardedHeaderFilter(), ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter.class)
```

Make sure you have set the following proxy_params in nginx:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

### Explaination:

It turns out that Chrome attaches an `Origin` header with POST requests.
The `Origin` header is matched with the actual request by the `CorsFilter` which uses `DefaultCorsProcessor` that uses `CorsUtils.isCorsRequest` in `org.springframework.web.cors` package.

Here, the request scheme turns out to be `http` and thus it does not match with the `Origin` header.

However, nginx sets `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` which should be used by spring.

In order to make spring use the `X-Forwarded-*` headers, we need to enable `ForwardedHeaderFilter` filter.