A webservice is being retrofitted to an existing spring web application, How to prevent the webservice from being redirected redirect to /login?
The targeted API is aadded to the ignoring matchers, which I would expect to simply invoke the webservice without further ado..
When the URL is posted from postman, the log indicates (as expected) that there is no security on this url.  I would expect that, detecting there is no security, the webservice endpoint would be invoked. However, instead, the framework redirects to /login and proceeds to attempt to validate on that basis.
What am I missing to allow the webservice to be invoked by an unauthenticated user?
Code snip1: webservice endpoint
@CrossOrigin
@PostMapping(value = "/ws/createArchive", headers = "Accept=*/*")
public String createArchive (@RequestAttribute String apiKey,  @RequestBody Map<String, Object > body) {
    logger.info("/ws/createArchive received:\r\n", body.toString());
    return "Ok";
}

Code snip 2: Spring web security initialization
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/", "/ws/**", "/index.html", "/app/**", "/register", "/favicon.ico","/ajax/cfgDownloadReport","/ajax/importLicense")
            ;
    }
    
   @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .addFilterBefore(new ForwardedHeaderFilter(), ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter.class) // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75860090/spring-cors-error-on-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-https
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll() // permitAll permits all authenticated users
        .requestMatchers("/applicationVersion").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/ajax/licenseValidation", "/ajax/cfgFetchAllNotifications", "/notification/search","/ajax/importLicense",
                    "/ajax/licenseValidation", "/ajax/cfgFetchAllNotifications", "/notification/searchCount",
                    "/ajax/jobExecutionParams","/ajax/keyValuePair/","/ajax/instanceregistry")
            .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().denyAll().and()
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .logout().deleteCookies(JWTFilter.getAuthorizationHeader()).invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionFixation().migrateSession()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
        .maximumSessions(2);

        return http.getOrBuild();
    }

URL posted from Postman:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-api/ws/createArchive?apiKey=12345

Log snip:
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,831 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/'], Filters=[]] (1/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,832 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/ws/**'], Filters=[]] (2/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,833 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - No security for POST /ws/createArchive?apiKey=12345
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,937 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/'], Filters=[]] (1/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,938 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/ws/**'], Filters=[]] (2/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,938 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/index.html'], Filters=[]] (3/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,938 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/app/**'], Filters=[]] (4/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,938 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/register'], Filters=[]] (5/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,938 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/favicon.ico'], Filters=[]] (6/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,939 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/ajax/cfgDownloadReport'], Filters=[]] (7/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,939 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/ajax/importLicense'], Filters=[]] (8/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,939 TRACE o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@b760802, org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter@208e2b0, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7e6707c5, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@380f5cac, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1ce6d2f2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@15b3c1bf, com.mycompany.myapp.JWTFilter@752534aa, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@130646f9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@59fdce16, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@792ce5eb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4e280414, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3b80ca33, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@676d03bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4a0a10b8]] (9/9)
http-nio-8080-exec-4 2024-04-22 15:41:35,939 DEBUG o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy - Securing POST /login?apiKey=12345


The correct solution to this question in my case was, instead of adding the url to the ignore matchers, to implement the apikey security filter, which was slated for implementation later in the project.  See Securing Spring Boot API with API key and secret .
